# Block redirect to other posts pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I have 2 tables: posts and users(their relation is many-to-many), User has many favorite_posts(with FavoritePost table(it consists of user_id and post_id).
So, i have a route:
 get 'favorite_posts', to: 'favorite_posts#index'
(users/:user_id/favorite_posts)
In my ability.rb:

```
class Ability 
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.new_record?
      can :read, [Post]
    else
      can :read, [Post]
      can :manage, [Post], owner_id: user.id
      can :manage, [FavoritePost], user_id: user.id
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller(favorite_posts_controller.rb):

```
class FavoritePostsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource through: :current_user

  def index
    @favorite_posts = User.find(params[:user_id]).favorite_posts
  end
```

So, i need to block redirect to pages with favorite posts of other user through ability.rb. What i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [quote](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/123) from a CanCan maintainer:

> CanCan can answer the question whether the user can or can't do
>   something, but what the app does from there is very context specific
>   and I don't think is a good fit for the `ability.rb` file.

If you don't want to let other users view the current user's favorite posts, it's best to put this in a `before_action` filter in your **favorite_posts_controller**:

```
 class FavoritePostsController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource through: :current_user
   before_action :correct_user, only: [:index] # add any other actions you want

   def index 
     @favorite_posts = current_user.favorite_posts.all
   end 

   private 

     def correct_user
       user = User.find(params[:user_id])
       redirect_to root_url unless current_user && current_user == user
     end
 end
```